# How to create a new Flutter project that targets Android KitKat and Android SDK 19? Which Flutter version should I use?

Tags: flutter, android-4.4-kitkat

I need to use a native Android library that uses SDK 19, so I need to create a new Flutter project that supports SDK 19 and Android KitKat. But I don't know which Flutter version I should change to for best support for SDK 19 and Android KitKat. I have checked the Flutter release documentation but I can't for the life of me find the appropriate Flutter version to use.

In case you wonder why I have to use such an old SDK version, is that I am using a Zebra SDK for one of their scanner devices and that's the version they currently have available and they recommend creating a project specifically for SDK 19 and KitKat.

Thanks!

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on - i think it is still valid, so newest flutter 1.24 should still work on android 4.1 (kitkat is 4.4 afair)

Comment: I will try v.1.12.13+hotfix.9-stable and come back with the results.

Comment: its 11 months old... even 11 months and 20 days

Comment: Maybe I should just skip using Flutter for this project. KitKat is really old.

Comment: and did try the newest flutter version?

Comment: @pskink yes but I got some errors, I can post them soon. I will try again with the newest Flutter version.